# Drop all the synonyms using cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I wanted to drop all the synonyms of a database (sql server 2008 r2) using cursor.
environment-database name- 'mydatabase', schema name- 'dbo'..
Can you please guide me as i did try but the statement of while .. end, is not able to drop the synonym.
what logic should be apply w.r.t cursor?

Answer (score 20):

No need to use a cursor.  Do it as set:

```
declare @n char(1)
set @n = char(10)

declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '' ) +
'drop synonym [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.synonyms

exec sp_executesql @stmt
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Jason's answer with some improvements

- Use Quotename() function to wrap the names in square brackets
- Initialize the @SQL variable to an empty string, this means that the isnull is not required, and means that when you concatenate the results of the query into a single string it doesn't get the type wrong. String literals in a concatenation can take the default nvarchar size and cause your resulting string to be truncated unexpectedly.
- Ensure the string literals are also nvarchar by using the N in front of them.
- Filter to the dbo schema only, as the OP requested.
- Add the sys schema to the sp_executesql call

Totally agree this is not something where you need a cursor.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
SELECT @SQL += N'DROP SYNONYM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name) + N';' + Char(13) + Char(10)
FROM sys.synonyms
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) = N'dbo'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```